# VBA If a relative reference to an active cell equals a certain text?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up an if statement that whose condition is that the cell two cells to the left of the active cell contains the text "Year" or "SqFt". If this is true, then I am deleting some cells. Here is my code guys. I am a beginner VBA person, so not really sure why I am getting an error message.

```
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = ("Year") Or ("SqFt") Then 
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents                   
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents                   
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).ClearContents
    End If
```

Comment: This will fail if the `ActiveCell` is in column `A`, and may fail if it is left of column `D`.

Comment: My active cell is in column I1!

Comment: You also need to repeat the `If` portion when using `Or`: `If ActiveCell.Offset(0, - 1) = "Year" Or ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "SqFt"`

Comment: You should start by watching this video:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: you haven't said what the error is and on which line it occurs? Also, you are clearing rather than deleting. You want to avoid ActiveCell and .Select and you can clear a range of more than one cell in one go rather than multiple lines doing one cell each.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. This should fix at least 2 errors in the `IF` statement - OR logic, and `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value` comparison

```
If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ("Year")) Or (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = ("SqFt")) Then
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).ClearContents
End If
```